# Unable to install nant on mac with mono verions 5.0+

Tags: macos, mono, nant

I am unable to install NAnt on my MacBook pro having Mono version greater than 4.0, to be precise Mono version is 5.16.0
Tried installing from the source using the command: make install prefix=installation-path which threw the error

```
cp -R lib/ bootstrap/lib
# Mono loads log4net before privatebinpath is set-up, so we need this in the same directory
# as NAnt.exe
cp lib/common/neutral/log4net.dll bootstrap
cp src/NAnt.Console/App.config bootstrap/NAnt.exe.config
gmcs  -target:exe -define:MONO,NET_1_0,NET_1_1,NET_2_0,ONLY_2_0 -out:bootstrap/NAnt.exe -r:bootstrap/log4net.dll \
        -r:System.Configuration.dll -recurse:src/NAnt.Console/*.cs src/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs
/bin/sh: gmcs: command not found
make: *** [bootstrap/NAnt.exe] Error 127
```

*Relatively new to scripting.

Comment: `gmcs` *was* an alias for `mcs` (Mono C# compiler) and `mcs` was deprecated in favor of `csc` (The open-source Microsoft Roslyn-based C# compiler), so replace `gmcs` with `csc` (which is a symlink to /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/csc)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am new to this and am not sure how I am supposed to achieve whatever u explained? Could u pls elaborate on that an help in the installation

Comment: Change `gmcs` to `csc` in your script

Comment: Am trying to install Nant on my mac and the command i used was make install prefix=installation-path, where exactly i need to replace gmcs with csc

Comment: ? You show `gmcs` in your question's script

Comment: @SushiHangover that whole thing was thre response I got when i tried to install nant using the command make install prefix=installation-path

Comment: Either modified the source script (if you are executing `make install..` locally then you have the source code) or you can try just creating an alias/symlink for `gmcs`

Comment: @SushiHangover I opened the solution in visual studio and replace all instances of gmcs with csc and tried to make install.. still gettting the same error. Also i tried creating symlink for gmcs like "ln -s gmcs path-for-csc" but again the doubt is my mac doesnt have gmcs.